# How to get value from Radiogroup and change in database

Tags: java, android, firebase, radio-group

I am working on an application in android studio with firebase where the user can change user settings such as name, phone number and bio.
I also need the ability to change a selected radio group button value. 
The Settings activity class is as follows

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mNameField, mPhoneField, mBio;
private Button mBack, mConfirm;
private RadioGroup mSport;
private ImageView mProfileImage;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private String userId, name, phone, bio, sport, profileImageUrl, userSex;
private Uri resultUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mPhoneField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    mBio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bio);
    mSport = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.sport);
    mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
    mBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    mConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

    getUserInfo();

    mProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
    mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveUserInformation();
        }
    });
    mBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    });
}


private void getUserInfo() {
    mUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if(map.get("name")!=null){
                    name = map.get("name").toString();
                    mNameField.setText(name);
                }
                if(map.get("phone")!=null){
                    phone = map.get("phone").toString();
                    mPhoneField.setText(phone);
                }
                if(map.get("bio")!=null){
                    bio = map.get("bio").toString();
                    mBio.setText(bio);
                }
                if(map.get("sport")!=null){

                }
                if(map.get("sex")!=null){
                    userSex = map.get("sex").toString();
                }
                if(map.get("sport") !=null){

                }
                Glide.clear(mProfileImage);
                if(map.get("profileImageUrl")!=null){
                    profileImageUrl = map.get("profileImageUrl").toString();
                    switch(profileImageUrl){
                        case "default":
                            Glide.with(getApplication()).load(R.mipmap.default_app_image).into(mProfileImage);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Glide.with(getApplication()).load(profileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

private void saveUserInformation() {
    name = mNameField.getText().toString();
    phone = mPhoneField.getText().toString();
    bio = mBio.getText().toString();
    int selectSport = mSport.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    final RadioButton sportButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectSport);
    if(sportButton.getText() == null){
        return;
    }
    Map userInfo = new HashMap();
    userInfo.put("name", name);
    userInfo.put("phone", phone);
    userInfo.put("bio", bio);
    userInfo.put("sport",sport);

    mUserDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo);
    if(resultUri != null){
        StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                Map userInfo = new HashMap();
                userInfo.put("profileImageUrl", downloadUrl.toString());
                mUserDatabase.updateChildren(userInfo);

                finish();
                return;
            }
        });
    }else{
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        resultUri = imageUri;
        mProfileImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
    }
}
```

and the XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.wk001764.finalproject.SettingsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:src="@mipmap/default_app_image" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="398dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Name" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:inputType="phone"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bio"
        android:layout_width="398dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Bio" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please Select the sport you want to change to:"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/sport"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/badminton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Badminton" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/basketball"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Basketball" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/boxing"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Boxing" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/cricket"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Cricket" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/football"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Football" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/golf"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Golf" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/hockey"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hockey" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rugby"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Rugby" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/swimming"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Swimming" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/tennis"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tennis" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:text="Save"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:text="Back"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How would I get the new selected value of the radio group and save it to the database?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
int radioButtonId = mSport.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = mSport.findViewById(radioButtonId);
int idx = mSport.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```

To get selected `RadioButton` Text in a RadioGroup, please use the following code:

```
 RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) mSport.getChildAt(idx);
 String selectedText = rb.getText().toString();
```

But note, this code will work **only** if the radio buttons are direct children of your RadioGroup. So you need to remove those "LinearLayouts". In fact, there is no need to use those layouts at all. You can set the orientation of your RadioGroup to "vertical", in your `.XML` file, using the following line of code:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: how would this be entered into the code? When I try and implement it, in the line 'View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonId)' radioButtonGroup is always highlighted red.

Comment: Changed with: `mSport`. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: ah, that makes much more sense, thank you!
Also,what would i put in 
if(map.get("sport") !=null){
                        
                    }

Comment: What you need to have there.

Comment: No  I can't seem to figure out what to put where

Comment: It's a straightforward example. Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Not as much as I hoped

Comment: I've tried several more times now, however when I thought it was working, i got this error:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference

Comment: This means that your `mSport` object is `null`. Make sure is instantiated correct. This code should work, I'm using it in one of my projects. So?

Comment: I spent the whole day searching a way to send data to firebase through radio buttons. Finally found a solution. Thank you so much! Upvoted!!!